# Why isn't the keyListener working?

Tags: java, swing, keyboard-events, keylistener, key-bindings

This is a pong game I made, but the only thing that is not working is the paddles moving. I am not sure how to make the keyboard work with the program. Here is the code for the main game:

```
//Project: A program where you play the game pong

//This module defines the properties of the user interface

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class pongframe extends JFrame
{
    private JLabel playerlefttitle;
    private JLabel playerrighttitle;
    private JLabel speedtitle;
    private JTextField speedfield;
    private JTextField playerleftscorefield;
    private JTextField playerrightscorefield;
    private JButton newgame;
    private JButton gobutton;
    private JButton pausebutton;
    private JButton quitgame;
    private Timer systemclock;
    private Timer paddleclock;
    private String speedstring;
    private int speed;
    private int leng = 10;
    private int delayinterval;
    private float millisecondpersecond = 1000.0f;
    private boolean win = false;
    private int playerleftscore=0;
    private int playerrightscore=0;
    private boolean rightup = false;
    private boolean rightdown = false;
    private boolean leftup = false;
    private boolean leftdown = false;
    private boolean barhit = true;
    private double direction=0;
    private pongoperations graphicalpanel;
    private Clockhandlerclass clockhandler;
    private PaddleClockHandlerClass paddleclockhandler;
    private PaddleHandlerClass paddlehandler;

    public pongframe()
    {
        super("Pong");
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        graphicalpanel = new pongoperations();
        graphicalpanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        add(graphicalpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        add(panel1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        c.insets = new Insets(0,0,10,10);
        newgame = new JButton("New");
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        panel1.add(newgame, c);
        speedtitle = new JLabel("Speed");
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        panel1.add(speedtitle, c);
        speedfield = new JTextField(3);
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        panel1.add(speedfield, c);
        quitgame = new JButton("Quit");
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 1;
        panel1.add(quitgame, c);
        playerlefttitle = new JLabel("Player Left");
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 3;
        panel1.add(playerlefttitle, c);
        playerrighttitle = new JLabel("Player Right");
        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 3;
        panel1.add(playerrighttitle, c);
        playerleftscorefield = new JTextField(2);
        playerleftscorefield.setEditable(false);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 4;
        panel1.add(playerleftscorefield, c);
        gobutton = new JButton("Go");
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 4;
        panel1.add(gobutton, c);
        pausebutton = new JButton("Pause");
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 4;
        panel1.add(pausebutton, c);
        playerrightscorefield = new JTextField(2);
        playerrightscorefield.setEditable(false);
        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 4;
        panel1.add(playerrightscorefield, c);
        buttonhandler myhandler = new buttonhandler();
        newgame.addActionListener(myhandler);
        gobutton.addActionListener(myhandler);
        pausebutton.addActionListener(myhandler);
        quitgame.addActionListener(myhandler);
        clockhandler = new Clockhandlerclass();
        paddleclockhandler = new PaddleClockHandlerClass();
        paddlehandler = new PaddleHandlerClass();
    }
    private class buttonhandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            graphicalpanel.reset();
            if(event.getSource() == newgame)
            {
                speedfield.setText("");
                playerleftscore = 0;
                playerrightscore = 0;
                playerleftscorefield.setText("0");
                playerrightscorefield.setText("0");
                graphicalpanel.reset();
                graphicalpanel.repaint();
                gobutton.setEnabled(true);
                speedfield.setEditable(true);
                newgame.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else if(event.getSource() == gobutton)
            {
                speedstring = speedfield.getText();
                leng = speedstring.length();
                if(leng == 0)
                    speed = 0;
                else 
                {
                    speed = Integer.parseInt(speedstring);
                    gobutton.setEnabled(false);
                    speedfield.setEditable(false);
                }
                newgame.setEnabled(false);
                delayinterval = (int)Math.floor(millisecondpersecond/speed + 0.5f);
                systemclock = new Timer(delayinterval, clockhandler);
                systemclock.start();
                paddleclock = new Timer(delayinterval, paddleclockhandler);
                paddleclock.start();
            }
            else if(event.getSource() == pausebutton)
            {
                gobutton.setEnabled(true);
                newgame.setEnabled(true);
                systemclock.stop();
            }
            else if(event.getSource() == quitgame)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Unkown error");
        }
    }
    private class Clockhandlerclass implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            if(event.getSource() == systemclock)
            {
                graphicalpanel.grabFocus();
                graphicalpanel.moveball(speed,delayinterval, direction, barhit);
                direction = graphicalpanel.changedirection(direction);

                if(win == false)
                {
                    barhit = graphicalpanel.barhits(barhit);
                    graphicalpanel.repaint();
                    win = graphicalpanel.winner();
                    playerleftscore = graphicalpanel.playerleftwin(playerleftscore);
                    playerrightscore = graphicalpanel.playerrightwin(playerrightscore);
                    playerleftscorefield.setText(Integer.toString(playerleftscore));
                    playerrightscorefield.setText(Integer.toString(playerrightscore));
                }
                else if(win == true)
                {
                    graphicalpanel.reset();
                    win = false;
                    systemclock.restart();
                    if(playerleftscore == 10)
                    {
                        newgame.setEnabled(true);
                        systemclock.stop();
                    }
                    else if(playerrightscore == 10)
                    {
                        newgame.setEnabled(true);
                        systemclock.stop();
                    }
                    graphicalpanel.repaint();
                }   
            }
            else
                System.out.printf("%s\n", "There is a bug in the clock.");
        }
    }
    private class PaddleClockHandlerClass implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            if(event.getSource() == paddleclock)
            {
                graphicalpanel.moveplayer1(rightup, rightdown);
                graphicalpanel.moveplayer2(leftup, leftdown);
                graphicalpanel.repaint();
            }
        }
    }
    private class PaddleHandlerClass implements KeyListener
    {
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event)
        {
        }
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event)
        {
            if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
            {
                rightup = true;
                System.out.println("Up");
            }
            else if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
                rightdown = true;
            if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W)
                leftup = true;
            else if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S)
                leftdown = true;
        }
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event)
        {
            if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
                rightup = false;
            else if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
                rightdown = false;
            if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W)
                leftup = false;
            else if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S)
                leftdown = false;
        }
    }
}
```

This next bit of code are the functions that I am using for the game:

```
//Project: A program where you play the game pong

//This module contains the graphics and algorithms used by this project.

import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;

public class pongoperations extends JPanel
{
    int widthofgraphicalarea;
    int heightofgraphicalarea;
    final int ballradius = 8;
    int ballxcoordinate;
    double ballycoordinate;
    int paddle1xcoordinate;
    int paddle1ycoordinate;
    int paddle2xcoordinate;
    int paddle2ycoordinate;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics graphicarea)
    {//function to paint the area
        super.paintComponent(graphicarea);
        this.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        widthofgraphicalarea = getWidth();
        heightofgraphicalarea = getHeight();
        //create paddle 1
        graphicarea.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        graphicarea.fillRect(paddle1xcoordinate, paddle1ycoordinate, 10, 50);
        //create paddle 2
        graphicarea.setColor(Color.RED);
        graphicarea.fillRect(paddle2xcoordinate, paddle2ycoordinate, 10, 50);
        //Give the ball a white color
        graphicarea.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        //The 3rd and 4th parameters below represent the diameter of the ball.
        graphicarea.fillOval(ballxcoordinate,(int)ballycoordinate,2*ballradius,2*ballradius);
    }//End of method paintComponent
    public void moveplayer1(boolean rightup, boolean rightdown)
    {
        if(rightup == true)
        paddle1ycoordinate -= 5;
        else if(rightdown == true)
        paddle1ycoordinate += 5;
        positionPlayer1(paddle1xcoordinate, paddle1ycoordinate);
    }
    public void moveplayer2(boolean leftup, boolean leftdown)
    {
        if(leftup == true)
        paddle2ycoordinate -= 5;
        else if(leftdown == true)
        paddle2ycoordinate += 5;
        positionPlayer2(paddle2xcoordinate, paddle2ycoordinate);
    }
    public void positionPlayer1(int x, int y)
    {
        this.paddle1xcoordinate = x;
        this.paddle1ycoordinate = y;
        repaint();
    }
    public void positionPlayer2(int x, int y)
    {
        this.paddle2xcoordinate = x;
        this.paddle2ycoordinate = y;
        repaint();
    }
    public void moveball(int speed, int delayinterval, double direction, boolean barhit)
    {
        if(barhit == true)
            ballxcoordinate+=1;
        else if(barhit == false)
            ballxcoordinate-=1;
        if(direction > 0)
            ballycoordinate = ballycoordinate + (double)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(direction));
        else if(direction < 0)
            ballycoordinate = ballycoordinate + (double)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(direction));
    }
    public boolean barhits(boolean barhit)
    {
        if(ballxcoordinate == paddle1xcoordinate+10 && (ballycoordinate >= paddle1ycoordinate && ballycoordinate <= paddle1ycoordinate+50))
            barhit = true;
        else if(ballxcoordinate+2*ballradius == paddle2xcoordinate && (ballycoordinate+2*ballradius >= paddle2ycoordinate && ballycoordinate+2*ballradius <= paddle2ycoordinate+50))
            barhit = false;
        return barhit;
    }
    public boolean winner()
    {
        if(ballxcoordinate+2*ballradius >= widthofgraphicalarea)
            return true;
        else if(ballxcoordinate+2*ballradius <= 16)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
    public int playerleftwin(int playerleftscore)
    {
        if(ballxcoordinate+2*ballradius >= widthofgraphicalarea)
            playerleftscore+=1;

        return playerleftscore;
    }
    public int playerrightwin(int playerrightscore)
    {
        if(ballxcoordinate+2*ballradius <= 16)
            playerrightscore+=1;

        return playerrightscore;
    }
    public double changedirection(double direction)
    {//function to change the direction of the ball to bounce of walls
        if((int)ballycoordinate+2*ballradius >= heightofgraphicalarea || (int)ballycoordinate+2*ballradius < 16)
            direction = -direction;
        return direction;
    }
    public void reset()
    {//reset the ball at middle of left side
        ballxcoordinate = widthofgraphicalarea/2 - ballradius;
        ballycoordinate = heightofgraphicalarea/2 - ballradius;
        paddle1xcoordinate = 10;
        paddle1ycoordinate = heightofgraphicalarea/2-25;
        paddle2xcoordinate = widthofgraphicalarea-20;
        paddle2ycoordinate = heightofgraphicalarea/2-25;
    }
}
```

Please someone help. Thanks in advance.

Another question if you can help is once this is finished how do I switch this over to applet form?

Comment: Have you tried `paddlehandler.addKeyListener(this);`?

Comment: error message that says:                            pongframe.java:111: error: cannot find symbol
                paddlehandler.addkeyListener(this);
                             ^
  symbol:   method addkeyListener(pongframe)
  location: variable paddlehandler of type pongframe.PaddleHandlerClass

Comment: well where did you want me to put it?

Comment: Do not use a `KeyListener` Swing components use [`KeyBindings`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Comment: @GolfinGamer Sorry, forgot to say you should put it right below `paddlehandler = new PaddleHandlerClass();` But because of David's comment, I don't think this will work anyway.

Comment: Thats where I put it in the first place and got the error.

Comment: The code that I have seen from an example from my professor, he used keyListener. So how does keyBindings help?

Comment: +1 for sscce, `KeyListener` is for AWT components where as `KeyBindings` is for Swing components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Do not use a `KeyListener` Swing components use [`KeyBindings`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).
- Dont extend `JFrame` class unnecessarily
- Swing components should be created on [`Event Dispatch Thread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)
- To set the size of your app (without `setSize(..)` call on `JFrame`) use appropiate LayoutManager when adding components buttons etc (which you do) and when drawing in `paintComponent` override `JPanel` `getPreferredSize()` and return an appropriate size which fits all drawings than call `pack()` on `JFrame` before setting it visible
- Dont forget to call `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` on `JFrame` so when *X* is pressed the *Event Dispatch Thread* and *Initial thread* are exited, or app will remain running in background.

But to solve your problem after `paddlehandler = new PaddleHandlerClass();` add:

```
  graphicalpanel.addKeyListener(paddlehandler);
```

the problem is you never added the `KeyListener` to any Component to *listen* for events.

The proper solution would be `KeyBindings` which would change your  `PaddleHandlerClass` like this:

```
private class PaddleHandlerClass {

    public PaddleHandlerClass(JComponent jc) {

        jc.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP"), "up");
        jc.getActionMap().put("up", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                rightup = true;
                System.out.println("Up");
            }
        });
        jc.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released UP"), "rel up");
        jc.getActionMap().put("rel up", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                rightup = false;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

than simply create the `paddleHandler` and pass instance of `JPanel` which keys we want to get:

```
paddlehandler = new PaddleHandlerClass(graphicalpanel);
```

Comment: 'graphicalpanel.addKeyListener(paddlehandler);'                    works. Thanks.

Comment: @GolfinGamer `KeyListener`s suffer from issues with lose of focus, they only respond when the component they are registered to has focus.  As David suggestions, you are better off using key bindings as they are capable of responding to a wider range of focus criteria (ie, when the window has focus for example)