# Java keylistener use arrow keys to move car

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I am trying to implement a keylistener to move the car in my program using the arrow keys.
Here is my code.

```
package moveCar;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CPanel extends JPanel{ 
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
CarComponent component;
public CPanel() {
    component = new CarComponent();
    JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
    JButton stopButton = new JButton("Stop");
    startButton.addActionListener(new StartAction());
    stopButton.addActionListener(new StopAction());

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    buttonPanel.add(startButton);
    buttonPanel.add(stopButton);

    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.add(component, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

class StartAction implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        component.setAnimation(true);
    }
}
class StopAction implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        component.setAnimation(false);
    }
}
}

package moveCar;

import javax.swing.*;

public class CarViewer  {
CPanel a = new CPanel();
public CarViewer(){
    a.add(new CPanel());
}
public static void main(String[] arg){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    //frame.setSize(800,200);
    frame.setTitle("This is strange .....");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setContentPane(new CPanel());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

I believe that is all the code you will need, but if you need my other code I can get that.
Thank you

Comment: Well... what is your question ?

Comment: Please tell us your problem

Comment: where on earth is the `KeyListener` declared? Anyhow Swing uses [`KeyBinding`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) and not `KeyListener`. See [this similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770185/why-isnt-the-keylistener-working/13770483#13770483)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added any key bindings to your application. Check out the Java tutorial on [swing key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for information on how to do this.

Comment: I do not know how to implement the keybindings

Answer (score -1):

You have to use addKeyListener:

```
addKeyListener(yourKeyListener);
```

See this [minimal example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JTextFieldaddKeyListenerKeyListenerl.htm).